# Getting "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." when content script sendResponse to background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a chrome extension, popup js will send a message to background and background will redirect the message to content script, after some network request, the result should be returned to the background and then popup js.

Below are some simplified pieces of my code.

popup js

```
$('.porintButton').click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'learningPointButton':
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'learning' }, callback);
            processResult();
            break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

backgound js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, request, response => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                // If I click learningPointButton, the line will excute, and log 'ERROR:  {message: "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."}' 
                console.log('ERROR: ', chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
                console.log('The Content Script got the following Message: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                sendResponse(response);
            }
        });
    });
    return true;
});
```

content script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.info('contentscript', request, sender);
    switch (request.action) {
        case 'learning':
            // this simulate network async request, will not work, 
            setTimeout(() => {
                sendResponse({ action: request.action, result: 'ok' });
            }, 0);
            // this works
            // sendResponse({ action: request.action, result: 'ok' });
            break;
    }
    // I have read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple and return true here
    return true;
});
```

If I change the message tunnel to [the Long-lived connections](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect), it will work, why?

Comment: 1. Why do you send the message through the background page instead of sending it directly to the content script? 2. Do you see the error in web page console? Which line in your code generates the error?

Comment: 3. Why `addListener(async` ? The callback is not an asynchronous function. Remove `async`.

Comment: @wOxxOm line 6 in background generate the error.

Comment: Well that's because `async` returns a Promise and chrome API doesn't work with promises so effectively your content script doesn't have a listener, which is what the error says. Remove `async` keyword.

Comment: @wOxxOm The chrome extension has restrictions, it cannot send messages from popup to content script, it can only relay from background.

Comment: There's no such restriction. The popup can send messages just fine.

Comment: (assuming popup means browserAction popup)

Comment: Ok, I will try, by the way, I really need async on addListener because I will invoke other async function using await in this callback, any ideas how to change it.

Comment: No, you don't need `async` there. It's a syntactic sugar for Promise-based functions. Like I said chrome API doesn't work with promises.

Comment: You'll have to declare a separate function and use it in the callback.

Comment: @wOxxO Thanks, it worked now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@wOxxO Thanks, you are right.

I rewrite the code using Promise style, and it works now.

my rewritten code like this.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.info('contentscript', request, sender);
    switch (request.action) {
        case 'learning':
            Promise.all([doLearning(), doLearning(), doLearning()])
                .then(unusedData => {
                    return getScore();
                })
                .then(scores => {
                    console.info(scores);
                    sendResponse({ action: request.action, result: 'ok', scores: scores });
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.error(e);
                    sendResponse({ action: request.action, result: 'error', message: e });
                });
            break;
        case 'score':
            getScore().then(scores => {
                console.info(scores);
                sendResponse({ action: request.action, result: 'ok', scores: scores });
            }).catch(e => {
                console.error(e);
                sendResponse({ action: request.action, result: 'error', message: e });
            });
            break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

And I can send message from popup to contentscript directly.